# How can i re-load parent page when popup page is closed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
public static string PopUpParentPage
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["PopUpParentPage"] == null)
        {
           return (string.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            return (string)(HttpContext.Current.Session["PopUpParentPage"]);
        }
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["PopUpParentPage"] = value;
    }
}
```

I have the above code that gets me the parent of a popup window.

And below is how i open the pop window from a link button click event in the parent window

```
protected void lnkOpenPopUp_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {
    string strScript = "<script>fnChangeLocationPopup();</script>";
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "openPopup", strScript);
}
```

This is also how i close the popup window by click a button on the popup page

```
protected void btnClosePopUp_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
  {
    string strScript = "<script>fnChangeLocationPopup();</script>";
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "closePopup", strScript);
}
```

Now what i want to is re-load the parent page so that data is refreshed. If i know the value of the parent page URL as retrieve in the first code snippet above, how can i get it refreshed on btnClosePopUp_Click once the popup form has closed?

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript:**  inside you function `fnChangeLocationPopup()` writebelow code

```
 window.location.reload();
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

this will redirect to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Close` event of Popup page using below code.
and write a code which reload the parent window using `.parent` property as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = closePopup;
function closePopup(){
window.parent.location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Just put above code in you Popup page in `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript

```
function myfunction() {
        if (window.opener != null) {
            opener.location.reload(true);
            window.close();
        }
    }
```